# How to import rlib in an rpython program to be translated using pypy's rpython

Tags: python, file-io, compilation, pypy

I am trying to do some file io in a program to be compiled with pypy's translate tool. Since open and os.open are not supported, I need rlib.streamio. I tried to do `import rlib` but it gives the following error

```
[translation:ERROR]  ImportError': import statement always raises [type ImportError: 'No module named rlib']
```

I translate using

```
$ ./pypy-1.4.1-src/pypy/translator/goal/translate.py myScript.py
```

How do I import rlib in myScript.py?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's

```
from pypy.rlib import streamio
```

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that pypy's translate looks for modules in the path of script (or installed modules), rather than its own system. Once I copied rlib into the current directory, I could compile it. I just had to

```
$ cp -r pypy-1.4.1-src/pypy/rlib .
```

Then

```
$ ./pypy-1.4.1-src/pypy/translator/goal/translate.py myScript.py
```

compiled successfully.